# Can't connect to hsqldb using jdbc java

Tags: java, database, jdbc, database-connection, hsqldb

I've got problem with connection to hsqldb using jdbc in java app. After parsing in main class from json to java I get 3 objects in list which i am trying to save to database.

Here is Dao class

```
public class EventDao {
private static final String URL = "jdbc:hsql:file:C:/Applications/appName//APPFOLDER";
private static final String USER = "sa";
private static final String PASS = "";
private Connection connection;

public EventDao() {
    try {
        Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDrive");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASS);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Couldnot establish connection");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void save(Event event) {
    final String sql = "insert into event(id,state,timestamp,type,host,alert) values (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    try {
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        preparedStatement.setString(1, event.getId());
        preparedStatement.setString(2, event.getState());
        preparedStatement.setString(3, event.getTimestamp().toString());
        preparedStatement.setString(4, event.getType());
        preparedStatement.setString(5, event.getHost());
        preparedStatement.setString(6, event.getAlert().toString());
        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void close() {
    try {
        connection.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And here is main when i am trying to save object Event to db (the list have 3 objects)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventParser eventParser = new EventParser();
    eventParser.mainLoop();
}

public void mainLoop() {
    try {
        EventDao eventDao = new EventDao();
        Map<String, EventWrapper> eventsFromFile = readEventsFromFile();
        List<Event> eventsToSave = calculateEventTime(eventsFromFile);
        for (Event event : eventsToSave) {
            eventDao.save(event);
        }
        eventDao.close();
        System.out.println(eventsFromFile);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

After debuging i found out that connection is null. Any ideas why?

Comment: Your connection URL is invalid. It should start with `jdbc:hsqldb:file:`. Also try commenting out the `Class.forName` statement as it may not be necessary and is wrong, too.

Comment: Changed URL, also comment Class.forName but after that i received error "java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:hsqldb:file:C:/Applications/appName//APPFOLDER"

Answer (score 0):

The correct form of the URL is:

```
URL = "jdbc:hsqldb:file:C:/Applications/appName/APPFOLDER";
```

The `Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDrive")` ensures the HSQLDB jar is on your classpath and loads the JDBC driver class form the jar. This was done without error. The error message indicates there is no driver available for the incorrect `jdbc:hsql:file` url.